# WordPress - programmatically add files to custom gallery

Tags: wordpress

I have a gallery added as a CUSTOM meta field called 'gallery'.

I've uploaded a bunch of url's as images through `media_sideload_image()`, serialized their id's and added that to the post gallery by `update_post_meta( $post_id , 'gallery', $serialized);`

This works in the backend: when I look at the post in the backend 'edit post' page, I can see all the pics in the gallery.  However, they are not showing in a slideshow on the frontend until I click on 'update' in the backend 'edit post' section.

My question: how do I programmatically 'click' the 'update' button after I've created the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

After you update the post gallery, you can programatically 'click' the 'update' button like this:

```
wp_update_post(['ID'=>$post_id]);
```

And if you happen to be using Search & Filter Pro, you should update the cache:

```
do_action('search_filter_update_post_cache', $post_id);
```